# Tangent space at the identity element of a lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let G be a lie group . we know a Lie group is a group with a smooth manifold structure s.t both the multiplication map $m$ and group inversion map $i$ are smooth .

Now by identifying $T_{(e,e)}(G\times G)\simeq T_eG\oplus T_eG $  , I can show that the tangent map $T_{(e,e)}m:T_eG\oplus T_eG\mapsto T_eG$ is given by $T_{(e,e)}m.(X,Y)=X+Y$.

Now , I wanna use this result to show that the tangent map $T_ei:T_e(G)\mapsto T_e(G)$ is given by $T_ei.X=-X$ since it seems hard to directly derive this result.

My attempt is to define a map $m':G\times G \mapsto G$  by  $ g.g^{-1}=e$.Then $T_{(e,e)}m'.(X,Y)=X+Y$= 0 .

Now the question is I don't know how to relate  $T_{(e,e)}m'.(X,Y)=X+Y$= 0 to $T_ei.X=-X$.I am also not sure about the correct way to define $m'$. Could someone help me with it ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the composition $G\rightarrow G\times G\rightarrow G$ where the first map sends $g$ to $(g,g^{-1})$, and the second map is $m$: it sends $(g,h)$ to $gh$.

This composition is constant, so its differential must be $0$.  On the other hand, if you compute the differential via the chain rule, you'll get the result you want.

Comment: Yes , this is the map I wanna construct , but how to relate this map to prove $T_ei.X=-X$

Comment: this map cant send to constant..

Comment: I think he was thinking consider the map $G \to G\times G \to G$ where the first map is $g\mapsto (g,g^{-1})$ and the second is multiplication.  This map is constant and the derivative of the first map is $X \mapsto (X, i_* X)$.  Thus the derivative of the composition is $X \mapsto X + i_* X$.  Since this must be zero (since the composition is constant), you get what you wanted.

Comment: Yes - What Eric said.  I'll fix this up in a second.  Sorry about the confusion!