# Is smoothness of multiplication redundant in the definition of Lie Group?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

It is well known that in the definition of Lie groups, we actually only need that the multiplication be smooth, since this implies that [inversion is smooth](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767704/smoothness-of-the-inversion-map-is-redundant-in-the-definition-of-lie-groups).

I'm now trying to solve the following exercise:

> Show that in the definition of Lie group, it is enough to assume that the inverse map $G \to G, g \mapsto g^{-1}$ is smooth.

I don't know how to attack this problem, and also couldn't find any other references to it in the literature.

Could I get some hints or references on how to solve it?

Comment: cite what text and page for exercise.

Comment: @coffeemath it's an exercise from some notes in my course, as far as I'm aware it's not in any other book

Comment: @TedShifrin: Is it associative?

Comment: @Moishe Believe it or not, that was the first thing I checked, but I was hasty and messed it up.

Comment: The title of your question is misleading.

Comment: @PaulFrost I think I see what you mean, I've changed it now. Is it better?

Comment: @ImHackingXD Of course!

Comment: I’m not sure it’s true: in the classical $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the non-smooth multiplication $(x,y) \longmapsto \sqrt[3]{x^3+y^3}$, the inverse function is $x \longmapsto -x$, which is smooth?

Comment: @Aphelli Oh wow, that's an awesome counterexample! This must be a typo in the notes then, I'll be sure to speak with the course instructor. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Aphelli You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested, I’m turning my comment (I was worried I was missing something) into an answer.

The statement is wrong. Consider the classical manifold $\mathbb{R}$, with the *non-smooth* “addition” law given by $(x,y) \longmapsto \sqrt[3]{x^3+y^3}$. This is a topological group law, and the inverse map is $x \longmapsto -x$, which is smooth.